# How to create a new column from existing column in IBM Data Refinery

Tags: ibm-data-refinery

I have 3 columns in my dataset and i want to add a new column based
on the value from one column.
For ex. I have Birthdate for a user and i want to create a new column with user's
age.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to split, combine columns or create new ones from existing columns. Eg: If you have one column called birthdate, you can use the Split operation from the operations panel to create birthyear, birthmonth, birthdate columns. From the year column, you can use the Calculate operation to calculate the age. Hope this helps